# Generating number with the same length as user input

Tags: java

I do not know whether the title suit my question I am about to ask.

```
String input = scan.nextLine();
for(int ip=0; ip<=input.length(); ip++)
 {
 Random rg = new Random();
 int n = rg.nextInt(ip=input.length());
 System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
 }
```

From the above code, I am prompting the user to input any amount of characters. Using the for loop to get the length of the input, the length of the random binary digits generated is different. how can I edit to have the random generator to printout the same length as the user input? example as shown:
my input: 99999
supposed output: 00110
my output:11

Comment: rg.nextInt(5) so it will give random value from 0 to 4 if you convert to binary you will get max 3 digit. you can append 0's in starting.

Comment: here's my question.. What if the user input 8 characters? random generator has to printout 8 characters as well

Answer (score 0):

you can use loop and check the value of n if its binary is having same length then print. code is as :

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    for(int ip=0; ip<=input.length(); ip++){
    Random rg = new Random();
    int n = 0;
    while((n = rg.nextInt(ip=input.length()*input.length())) < Math.pow(2, input.length()-1)
            && (n = rg.nextInt(ip=input.length()*input.length())) > Math.pow(2, input.length()))
    {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// note that StringUtils in org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
    private static final String getRandomBinaryNumber() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter input: ");
        String input = scanner.next();
        System.out.println();
        int len = input.length();
        System.out.println("Input length: " + len);
        Random rg = new Random();
        Integer randomInt = rg.nextInt((int) Math.pow(2, len));
        String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(randomInt);
        final String result = StringUtils.leftPad(binaryString, len, "0");
        System.out.println("Random output: " + result);
        return result;
    }
```